# Systemd service: blob data and return code

Tags: bash, qt5, raspbian, systemd

In Raspbian Stretch Lite I created the following systemd service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Autostart
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/home/pi/autostart.sh
User=pi
Group=pi

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here the content of autostart.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh -ex

export TERM=linux
clear   
mkdir -p /home/pi/logs
/home/pi/bin/./TestApp&
```

The script is actually executed (I added a debug echo to a file) but the application is not launched. It's a Qt5 console application, not a GUI one.

Trying to manually launch the script (i.e. `./autostart.sh`) works as expected.
Instead, manually start the service leads to this output:

```
$ sudo systemctl start autostart.service
$ systemctl status autostart.service
● autostart.service - Autostart
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/autostart.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2017-09-28 19:56:33 CEST; 9s ago
  Process: 1351 ExecStart=/home/pi/autostart.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1354 (code=exited, status=127)

Sep 28 19:56:33 localhost systemd[1]: Starting Autostart...
Sep 28 19:56:33 localhost autostart.sh[1351]: + export TERM=linux
Sep 28 19:56:33 localhost autostart.sh[1351]: + clear
Sep 28 19:56:33 localhost autostart.sh[1351]: [34B blob data]
Sep 28 19:56:33 localhost systemd[1]: Started Autostart.
Sep 28 19:56:33 localhost systemd[1]: autostart.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
Sep 28 19:56:33 localhost systemd[1]: autostart.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 28 19:56:33 localhost systemd[1]: autostart.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

It's ok the mkdir command is not executed (the directory is already there), but I don't understand why application is not executed.

What could I do to get more information about what's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, [running in the background is not the same as forking](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56495/whats-the-difference-between-running-a-program-as-a-daemon-and-forking-it-into).

You can get rid of your autostart script and make a simpler `systemd` config file.

- remove `Type=forking`. The default is `Type=simple`, which will handle running your app in the background for you.
- Set `Environment="TERM=linux"` directly in the system configuration.
- You can have multiple `ExecStart=` lines. Add a first one that is `ExecStart=-/bin/mkdir -p /home/pi/logs`, the extra "dash" there will allow the command to 'succeed' even if the directory has already been made.
- Finally, run your app with `ExecStart=/home/pi/bin/TestApp`

Related man pages are `man systemd.service`, `man systemd.exec`, or look up any directive with `man systemd.directives`.

Comment: It says: "autostart.service: Service has more than one ExecStart= setting, which is only allowed for Type=oneshot services. Refusing.". Anyway I solved moving the `mkdir` command in another script that runs earlier.

Comment: You can only have one `ExecStart`, however you can have multiple `ExecStartPre`, and `ExecStartPost` commands. See the guide [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html).